# Redux pass up/refresh state from current page

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a react app ([repo](https://bitbucket.org/cclloyd9785/opensrd-fullstack/src)) that I want to use redux to store the state universally, so the root app can access it.

For example: one page has a GET API call that populates the page.  That works fine and all, but I'm confused as to how to do a couple things.

1. How can I use variables in the redux action, to give the action say the ID of the model and have it return the model (API returns json).
2. How can I then pass that state up so that a higher ordered component (such as the base App.js) can access the state, so that I can use variables from the current page in the navigation.
3. What/when is the best way/time to update the redux state so that the changes reflect across anywhere using the redux state?

Specifically (in this project):  If you are on `localhost/spells/X` with X being the model ID, how can I pass the state up from that page's container component (in this case LayoutSpellView) up to MaterialUIApp

```
index.js
  |--App.js
     |--MaterialUiApp
        |--Router
           |--LayoutSpellView (pass state up to MaterialUiApp)
```

Answer (score 5):

With Redux you don't pass the state up or down. You update the global state with your action creators and reducers. Wherever you need to reach the state you connect your components to the state and use it. You have a store and it includes a global state. That global state may contain multiple different states.

1. You can use payload or any other name, variable with your action creator. In your reducer you can get those with action.payload, action.id, etc.
2. As I explained in the first paragraph, you update your state whenever you need. After that you connect any component to your state wherever you need.
3. There is no best time or best way to do that. This is up to your code and app logic.

Of course there are some best practices but we can't talk about them so broad. After you are getting involved with Redux you will see some of them around. For example I said "we don't pass up or down the state with Redux". This is true but sometimes to avoid so many `connect`s around components we use container apps, connect that app to store (you reach state via store actually) and then pass the related state parts to the related components.

I recommend Redux's own documentation as starting point: https://redux.js.org/

Answer (score 0):

To help you see the data flow, here's a sketch of how everything ties together. In my example code below, this is the data flow:

1. Clicking the "Load Comments" button dispatches a thunk with the parameter `userId`. (A [thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) is an async action.)
2. The thunk uses the `userId` to make its async call, and `then` dispatches an action `setComments(comments)` with the received comments as its payload.
3. The Comments reducer catches that action and updates the Redux state with the `comments` array.
4. The Container to updates `comments` in mapStateToProps
5. The Component receives the updated `comments`, and displays them in the `<ul>`

```js
    // actions.js
    export const SET_COMMENTS = "MyApp/setComments";
    export const setComments = comments => ({
      type: SET_COMMENTS,
      payload: comments
    });

    // thunks.js
    import { setComments } from './actions';
    export const getCommentsAsync = id => dispatch => {
      return axios
        .get(`http://localhost:5000/comments/${id}`)
        .then(comments => dispatch(setComments(comments)));
    };

    // reducer.js
    import { SET_COMMENTS } from './actions';
    const initialState = {
      comments: []
    };

    export const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case SET_COMMENTS:
          const comments = action.payload;
          return {
            ...state,
            comments
          };
        default:
          return state;
      }
    };

    // components.js
    export default function CommentsList({ comments, loadComments, userId }) {
      return (
        <div>
          <ul>
            {comments.map(comment => <li key={comment.id}>{comment.body}</li>)}
          </ul>
          <button onClick={() => loadComments(userId)}>Load Comments</button>
        </div>
      );
    }

    // containers.js
    import { connect } from "react-redux";
    import { getCommentsAsync } from "./thunks";
    import CommentsList from "./components";

    mapStateToProps = state => ({
      comments: state.comments,
      userId: state.user.id
    });

    mapDispatchToProps = {
      loadComments: getCommentsAsync
    };

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CommentsList);
```